# Razor Pages set current date on page load

Tags: asp.net-core, razor-pages

I'm new to razor and .net, i have a page on an ASP Net Razor project where i popup a modal with a form inside. Inside the form there is a datepicker and i want to set the system date when the page loads and evenly keep it editable.
i've already tried with

- `@{ string dateNow = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd MM yyyy"); }`
- `<input asp-for="intervento.Data" class="form-control" type="date" value="@dateNow" />`

it retrieves the correct date but can't display it. how can i solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your date should be in the following format `yyyy-MM-dd`.

So it would look like this:

```html
<input type="date" value="2020-10-23">
```

Comment: It worked thanks, i setted the ToString with this "yyyy-MM-dd" instead of "dd MM yyyy"

Answer (score 1):

Presumably, `Intervento.Data` is a `DateTime` property of your PageModel? If so, you should add a `DataType` attribute to specify that it represents a date, not a time:

```
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
public DateTime Data { get; set; }
```

Then you don't need to specify the `type` on the input. The tag helper will generate the correct value based on the attribute. Also, if you set a default value on the property:

```
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
public DateTime Data { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;
```

you won't need to set the value of the input either. ASP.NET will take care of formatting the value correctly to an ISO 8601 format that the input can work with. So the following will suffice:

```
<input asp-for="intervento.Data" class="form-control" />
```